# Assign existing SNS Topic to Alarm in Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-sns

I have an existing SNS topic that isn't managed with Terraform that I want to reference so I can assign it within an `aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm.alarm_actions` list. When trying to run plan or apply I'm getting the following message:

> unknown resource 'aws_sns_topic.my-alerts' referenced in variable aws_sns_topic.my-alerts.arn

Judging by the message I'm guessing I have to create an SNS resource somehow but I'm not sure how to attach/reference it with the existing topic.

I'm referencing the existing topic in a data block:

```
data "aws_sns_topic" "my-alerts" {
  name = "my-alerts"
}
```

Then trying to use later in an alarm like:

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm" "app-health-alarm" {
  alarm_name                = "app-health-alarm"
  comparison_operator       = "GreaterThanOrEqualToThreshold"
  evaluation_periods        = "2"
  metric_name               = "ApplicationComponetHealthRequestFailing"
  namespace                 = "ApplicationComponetHealth"
  period                    = "300"
  statistic                 = "Average"
  dimensions                = {
                                component="my-app"
                              }
  threshold                 = "1"
  alarm_description         = "Checks the health of the app"
  datapoints_to_alarm       = "2"
  alarm_actions             = ["${aws_sns_topic.my-alerts.arn}"]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When referencing a data source you need to prefix it with `data.`

So in your case it should be:

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm" "app-health-alarm" {
  alarm_name                = "app-health-alarm"
  comparison_operator       = "GreaterThanOrEqualToThreshold"
  evaluation_periods        = "2"
  metric_name               = "ApplicationComponetHealthRequestFailing"
  namespace                 = "ApplicationComponetHealth"
  period                    = "300"
  statistic                 = "Average"
  dimensions                = {
                                component="my-app"
                              }
  threshold                 = "1"
  alarm_description         = "Checks the health of the app"
  datapoints_to_alarm       = "2"
  alarm_actions             = ["${data.aws_sns_topic.my-alerts.arn}"]
}
```

Comment: Thanks @ydaetskcoR. That also uncovered another issue though, you're not allowed to define the `arn` field in the `data.aws_sns_topic` block. Removing that and just referencing by name did the trick.